# gRPC client failing to connect with server with SSL/TLS

Tags: java, ssl, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to connect to gRPC server which has TLS enabled but doesn't require a client certificate.
I have used many combinations using NettyChannelBuilder and ManagedChannelBuilder.

```
NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget("host:443")
                    .useTransportSecurity()
                    .keepAliveTime(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .keepAliveTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS)
                    .enableRetry()
                    .build();
```

Error is

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

Underlying exception is

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

The server's certificate is not trusted. You should get a CA to issue a certificate for the server. If it is already a valid cert, make sure to provide the "certificate chain" when configuring the server, not just the bare server certificate.

If you didn't intend to use a typical "browser-trusted CA," you can sign the certificate with your own CA and use that CA's certificate as a trust source:

```java
ChannelCredentials certs = TlsChannelCredentials.newBuilder()
    // Could also be a server's self-signed cert
    .trustManager(new File("path/to/ca.pem"))
    .build();
NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget("host:443", certs)
    .keepAliveTime(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .keepAliveTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

There are many sites and scripts that describe how to make your own CA and sign server certificates, if that is what you end up wanting. For reference, [this is the process for gRPC's tests](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/testing/src/main/resources/certs/README).